# non-static field, error even when i declare the function as static

Tags: c#, winforms

I am sill get a 
"An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property..."
error even when i declare it as static. 
I cant seem to hack out a fix for it. I have spent enough time on it and need help or this is my doom.

I also tied to set:

```
TestFeature test = new TestFeature();
```

and use

```
static public void DispData()
{
  test.richTextBox1.Text = "1";
}
```

My goal is to dump a whole bunch of data incoming from com port into a richtextbox1.

```
dump[i] = string.Format("{0:X2}", hex.ToString());
DispData(ref string[] dump);
```

here is the full code:

```
namespace SW_Public
{
  public partial class TestFeature : Form
  {
    public TestFeature()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.Text = FRM_Title.PadLeft(5);
      richTextBox1.Text = "RTB1";
      richTextBox2.Text = "RTB2";
    }

    .....

    static public void DispData(ref string[] dump)
    {
      richTextBox1.Text = dump;
    }

    static void DisplayData(Byte Cmd, Byte[] RxData, int len)
    {

      switch (Cmd)
      {
        case (int)RXCMD.CMD_GETVERSION:
        .....

        case (int)RXCMD.CMD_RMEM:
        {
          string[] dump = new string[512]; 
          for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
          {
            byte hex = RxData[i];
            dump[i] = string.Format("{0:X2}", hex.ToString());
            DispData(ref string[] dump);           
          }
          break;
        }
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `static` and `instance`? Also, can you please reduce the code sample to just the part that's causing a problem?

Comment: Sorry to say, but this much code is not usually what people will spend their valuable time on. Please read this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then **[edit]** your question, and supply us with **the shortest code that demonstrates your issue**.

Comment: richTextBox1 obviously lives outside that static call.

Comment: Sorry, no one is going to read all that code.  However, your problem is that you are likely trying to reference an instance variable (richTextBox1) from a static method.  A static method is related to the class as a whole and not to any particular instance.  As a result, it has no `this` reference (i.e., a reference to the instance being operated on).  Instance variables are effectively `this.VariableName`, so, without the `this`, you can get to `VariableName` (I'm saying "variable" but I mean any of field, property, method).  When you are in a static method, you can only reach static stuff.

Comment: [The exception message says more than what you told us](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all of the static modifiers from all of the methods in the class.

You cannot access instance variables or methods directly from within static methods.